# check if file/folder exists and perform actions in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following code:

```
- name: check if file/folder exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  register: check_file
  with_items:
  - ['{{ source_folder }}','/etc/file', '/usr/file', '/root/dir', '/etc/test']

- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_file }}"
    #msg: "{{ check_file.stat.exists }}"
    #msg: "{{ check_file.results }}"

- name: Backup files
  copy:
   src: "{{ item }}"
   dest: "{{ backup_folder }}/{{ datetime }}/files"
  with_items:
  - ['{{ source_folder }}','/etc/file', '/usr/file', '/root/dir', '/etc/test']
  ignore_errors: "{{ not failure_is_critical }}
```

What I'm trying to do is check for the files/folders and if they don't exist continue the backup and write some info in the logs, something like:

```
folder1 found - OK
file1   found - OK
folder2 not found -skipping
file2   not found -skipping
```

And at the end show a result of full backup (success) or partial backup (fail)

Answer (score 4):

maybe your can try this : loop onto your stat results, and add condition of existence for each item

```
- name: Backup files
  copy:
    src: "{{ 'item.stat.path }}"
    dest: "{{ backup_folder }}/{{ datetime }}/files"
  loop: "{{ check_file.results }}"
  when: item.stat.exists      
  ignore_errors: "{{ not failure_is_critical }}
```

[EDIT] replaced `item.item.name` with `item.stat.path` like suggested by @anarchist

Comment: It gives this error: MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'

Comment: i was not sure about this, so before -name: Backup files, printout your var with :

    - name: debug
      debug:
        var: check_file

and then run again and try to change "item.item.name" with the good var

Comment: Ok, i am using 'item.stat.path' and the code works now. I still need to print out in the logs somehow files that have been backed up, files skipped and a result of 'partial' or 'full' backup

Comment: try to register results from your copy module and print with debug, you'll have the backed up files, for the files skipped, you need to create a task and print the files 'when: not item.stat.exists'

maybe... 

try to figure it out if you understand my logic

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it like this to get the result:

```
- name: Set check files result
  set_fact:
    store_check_file: "{{ check_file.results | map(attribute='stat.exists') | list }}"

- name: Set backup result
  set_fact:
    backup_result: "{{ 'partial' if false in store_check_file else 'full'}}"
```

Then i can print it with debug